# Is there a program to show which folders on my hard drive take up the most space?

Tags: windows-7

I have about 2/119 GB left on my SSD and was wondering if there's a good way to get an overview of which folders contain the largest files so I can move it over to my HDD.

Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use the program 'treesize free'. Does the job perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) is an excellent (and free) option. It scans your file system and then sorts by the amount of disk space used. You can drill down into each of the folders, just like in Explorer. It also gives you a visual representation of all of the files and folders on your drive.

Answer (score 0):

A nice software is [spacemonger](http://download.cnet.com/SpaceMonger/3000-2248_4-10050288.html), it shows folder sizes in a picture like this:

[image]