# Under Properties in Windows 8.1, how can "Size on disk" exceed the capacity of the drive?

Tags: windows-8, disk-space

I have a 2 TB NAS, Drive M, connected to my PC. If I right click on M, under Properties it shows:

Used space 530GB
Free space 1.26TB.

But, if I right click the individual sub folders they show:

Size: 350GB
Size on disk: 2.38TB

Size: 141GB
Size on disk: 252GB

Size: 36GB
Size on disk: 100GB

This gives a total of 2.73TB. How is this possible?

Comment: post some pictures of the issue

Comment: Are any sub directories shortcuts to directories on other disks?

Comment: Sub directories are all on NAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, Windows does not calculate the size on disk correctly. As author of the tool  [TreeSize](https://superuser.com/questions/594124/is-there-a-program-to-show-which-folders-on-my-hard-drive-take-up-the-most-space/594126#594126) I know that this can be difficult. Possible reasons might be [hardlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) or a kind of sub-block deduplication which the NAS does internally. Both is difficult to track for disk space usage software, especially the deduplication. Both leads to blocks of the disk being used for multiple files.

Often TreeSize provides more reliable results. You may consider using the fully functional 30 day trial of [TreeSize Personal](http://www.jam-software.de/treesize_personal/), switch TreeSize to the mode "Allocated Space", or even better enable the new "Details" tab and post a screenshot.

Comment: But, as you must know, TreeSize Free does not support network drives.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the trial of TreeSize Personal should do the trick then.